# pg_dump hangs when launched from Eclipse RCP application

Tags: java, postgresql, eclipse-rcp, postgresql-9.3, pg-dump

My PostgreSQL is 9.3

I have an Eclipse RCP application that calls a method in Spring application that launches Python script that launches pg_dump command.

- pg_dump command works when launched from console
- the python script that calls the command works
- the Spring application method launched with JUnit works fine
- when the method is called from Eclipse RCP application **it hangs**. Without any output.

I have come accross [this report](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/BAY114-DAV114EEFC7F6023D640831B4A3A80%40phx.gbl#BAY114-DAV114EEFC7F6023D640831B4A3A80@phx.gbl) that describes a similar problem. But I cannot find any solution or workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not related to Eclipse RCP but to Hibernate which locked the table that I wanted to backup because the table was created and pg_dump was called in the same @Transactional method. That is why pg_dump froze. It is strange that pg_dump didn't produce any error message, that made it quite difficult to debug.